# Compiler Does No Constant Folding for Masking Class

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, gcc4.8, constantfolding

For an embedded project, I use helper classes for flags and masks. For unknown reasons, the code of the mask class is not correctly constant folded as expected.

A minimal implementation of the mask is shown below:

```
template<typename Enum, typename MaskValue>
class EnumMask
{
public:
    constexpr inline EnumMask() noexcept : _mask(0) {}
    constexpr inline EnumMask(Enum enumValue) noexcept : _mask(maskFromEnum(enumValue)) {}
    constexpr inline EnumMask(const std::initializer_list<Enum> enumValues) noexcept : _mask(maskFromEnum(enumValues.begin(), enumValues.end())) {}
    constexpr inline operator MaskValue() const noexcept { return _mask; }
private:
    constexpr static inline MaskValue maskFromEnum(const Enum enumValue) noexcept {
        return (static_cast<MaskValue>(1)<<static_cast<uint8_t>(enumValue));
    }
    constexpr static inline MaskValue maskFromEnum(
        typename std::initializer_list<Enum>::const_iterator it,
        typename std::initializer_list<Enum>::const_iterator end) noexcept
    {
        return (it == end ? static_cast<MaskValue>(0) : (maskFromEnum(*it)|maskFromEnum(it+1, end)));
    }
private:
    const MaskValue _mask;
};
```

The class is used as shown in the following example:

```
class Driver
{
public:
    enum Pin : uint8_t {
        GPA0 = 0x00,
        GPA1 = 0x01,
        GPA2 = 0x02,
    };
    typedef EnumMask<Pin, uint16_t> PinMask;
    void setPinDirection(const uint16_t mask, bool direction);
    inline void setPinDirection(const PinMask &mask, bool direction) {
        setPinDirection(static_cast<uint16_t>(mask), direction);
    }
};

void main()
{
    Driver d;
    d.setPinDirection({Driver::GPA0, Driver::GPA1}, true);
}
```

The code is compiled using GCC 4.8.3 with the option `-Os`. I would expect, the compiler will resolve this code into a single value, yet it actually creates a function to calculate the mask from the values.

***Is there a particular reason in my code, which prevents the a proper const folding?***

Comment: GCC 4.x is an ancient compiler. GCC latest is currently 8.x.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I am aware of this. For embedded platforms, you sadly have to work with the best you get.

Comment: I've never understood why embedded platforms are thought to be so special in this regard. On _all_ platforms, you have to work with the best you get, but the key is to make sure you actually are working with the best.

Comment: Only compiler writers have some remote chance of answering then. In the meantime, try various combinations of macros and other inline functions.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I have no idea why compilers for embedded systems are so bad as well. For what it's worth, Arduino is on gcc 4.9.2

Comment: @NeilButterworth For desktop, you have a few and well understand instruction sets. Large groups invest a lot of time to adapt all compilers to it. For embedded you have 100+ of different instruction sets and CPUs, if you are lucky, a very small group actually writes a backend for a compiler for the MCU you use.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that - one major reason for selecting an embedded platform should be tool support for that platform, but it doesn't seem to be.

Comment: Embedded systems are often still buildable from upstream GCC source. It's just that there aren't precompiled binaries.

Comment: Instead of a constructor taking an `initializer_list`, just let a templated constructor take a variadic number of value arguments.

Comment: @o11c Thank you for the hint, I actually found a way to get gcc 7.2.1 working with the project. It supports `C++14`, so this should actually solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation is actually very simple:

The `begin()` and `end()` members of `std::initializer_list` are `constexpr` only as of C++14.

See [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/begin)

Comment: Compiling with the latest gcc in C++20 mode doesn't help. The issue is that -Os makes the compiler very shy about inlining / unrolling, since that may increase the code size. However, it is also required to compute the final value. -O1 gives better results in this case.